# SSRS in Visual Studio - breaking one table into two rows

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I created a dataset that contains more than 10 fields. But the page can only hold, say 8 fields (after exporting to PDF). Is there a way to "move" those remaining 2 fields to the next row? So each record will have two rows of headers and two rows of data.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an extra row to the header by simply right-clicking one of the header textboxes, and then insert row below or above as required.

Then in your detail row, do the same thing, and then on the additional row you just added, set the textboxes to the remaining fields.